# How to Take Lists of Any Types as Function Parameters Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, function-parameter

Hello I want to take lists of any type e.g. `[Int]`, `[Char]`, etc as parameters to a function.

Basically all I want to do is something along the lines of:

```
xyz :: [a] -> [a] -> (Int, Int)
```

Were `[a]` could be a list of any type.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: What do you want `xyz` to actually *do*? What is stopping it working now?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you pretty much got it already. Just write the signature like that and define your function. Except in a real-life application you will (probably; see @amalloy's comment) need to require `a` to belong to some type class, in order to do something meaningful with it:

```
xyz :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] -> (Int, Int)
xyz ls1 ls2 = (x, y) where
    x = fromInteger $ toInteger $ sum ls1
    y = fromInteger $ toInteger $ sum ls2
```

Comment: `xyz a b = (length a, length b)`